# JSQMessages.h not found

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I added [JSQMessageViewController](https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController) to my project. I went to the bridging header file and added `#import <JSQMessages.h>' and I get the error`JSQMessages.h not found'.

Why is Xcode not able to find it?

[image]

Comment: try #import "JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessages.h", it might be in a subfolder

Comment: yes that solved the problem. Feel free to add to the answer and i will mark it right. I ran into another problem IN JSQMessages.h, mind taking a look?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29858715/error-in-jsqmessages-h

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try #import "JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessages.h", it might be in a subfolder since the icon in your sidebar is blue.