# Error in JSQMessages.h

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I added JSQMessageViewController to my project. I went to the bridging header file and added `#import "JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessages.h"` and I get the following error in `JSQMessages.h`.

Why is Xcode not able to find it?

[image]

Comment: Did you copy or make a reference to the folder when you dragged it in? Blue folders normally means create a reference.

Comment: I copied the folders should I only make a reference?

Comment: No you should copy the entire group. But they should be yellow, not blue. I had a similar problem. Try removing the folder and trash it. Then empty trash. Then drag it in and check that it is grouped not referenced. Other than that, you could try and take all the files out of their individual folders to make it easier for the compiler to find. Let me know if it doesn't work and I'll have another look at what I did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer might be more opinion based, but I would delete your jsqmessagesviewcontroller folder, then when you drag it into your project just choose create groups instead of folders. Then you won't have to worry about subdirectory issues

**EDIT:**

Make sure it looks like this when you drag it into xcode (Copy items if needed, create groups and add to targets 'name of project' (not the Tests target) )
[image: Drag-n-drop folder into xcode]

Then you should be able to see this when in autocompletion when your typing your includes:

[image: autocomplete]

And you should also see the JSQMessagesViewController files in compile sources like so (I highlighted some to show you):
[image: selected jsqmessagesviewcontroller files]

If those files aren't in there, click the plus at the bottom of compile sources and select all the files in the jsqmessagesviewcontroller subdirectory and click add.

Hope this helps!

Comment: didn't help. i will keep trying :(

Comment: Did you include it in compile sources under build phases?

Comment: What should be included in the compile sources? JSQMessages.h? It does not show up.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your clear directions helped. I had "Create folder references" selected instead of "create groups", that made the differences. I don't know what the difference between them is so will research. Marked yours as the answer and also +1.